# I want a C compiler with a configurable bit size

Tags: compiler

The C language is infamous for not specifying the size and format of the built-in types:

- A "byte" (char) can be anything from 8 bits and up
- An "int" can be any number of chars as long as it fits a minimum number of values
- Integers are not required to use every bit
- Not all bit patterns in an integer has to be valid
- Signed integers are not necessarily two's-complement
- ...and more!

There is a hypothetical computer called the [DeathStation 9000](http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/DeathStation-9000) designed to break every assumption simultaneously.

However, I don't own this machine, so now I am looking for a proof-of-concept C compiler that can be configured to vary a lot of these features. A hypothetical example:

```
deathcc --char_bits=13 --ones-complement --endian=interleaved main.c
```

I would like such a compiler to check for possible portability issues.

Comment: The DeathStation9000 might have emulators